# Can't pass state with Link compoment. Why is state undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I'm trying to learn 'react-router' and I'm doing an app that has a input field that gives you a dropdown with links to various trainstations in Europe and when you click on that link it will render a component, in this case the `Station` component and show more details about the station.

For this application I will have to do two calls to an external API. The first one is to find the trainstations and display them in the dropdown. This works and from there I can get the name of the station and put it in the dropdown list, I also get an `id` which I will use for a query to the second API to get the details of the station. This will happen when the user clicks on the station in the dropdown. This works right now. My problem is that by the moment the user clicks the station in the dropdown, I've lost the name of the station. I want to pass it down somehow to the Station compoment.

This is my Station component:

```
const Station = (props) => {
 return (
  <h1>Station name: {props.location.state.name}</h1>
 )
}

export default Station;
```

Here is the Dropdown component, for simplicty I've hardcoded two stations to try and make it work, otherwise the dropdown is a list of stations that match the users query.

```
const Dropdown = (props) => {

return (
<ul>
  <li>
    <Link to={'/station/London'} key="lon" state={{name: 'London Central Station'}}>London </Link>
  </li>
  <li>
    <Link to={'/station/Paris'} key="par" state={{name: 'Paris Central Station'}}>Paris</Link>
  </li>
</ul>
  )
  }

export default Dropdown;
```

I've tried to pass down the station name with the `state` prop in the `Link` component but when the `Station` component mounts the `props.location.state` is undefined.

Lastly here are my Routes:

```
const Details = (props) => {
return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
      {/* <Route path='/station/:id' render={(props) => (<Station {...props} data={props}/>)} /> */}
      <Route path='/station/:id' component={Station} />
    </Switch>
    )
   }

export default Details;
```

In this component I tried both methods of passing props but I still can't make it work. The only solutions that I figured out is

- To make another call to the API to get the station name again which isn't optimal
- To save the name from the dropdown and set the name when clicked and then update the state of the parent component and pass it down to the Station component, which also isn't an optimal solution when I can figure out how to pass the parameters directly from the `Link` component.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the documentation, there's no `state` prop on the `Link` component itself but there is a `state` key as part of the `to` prop:

```js
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/courses",
    search: "?sort=name",
    hash: "#the-hash",
    state: { fromDashboard: true }
  }}
/>
```

Source: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link/to-object

Comment: Can't believe it. That was it. I din't even notice it, got tunnel vision I guess. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Easily done when you're in the zone :)